# DTF CustomAction to WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action, dtf

I'm using a DTF immediate custom action. The Custom Action takes minimum of 5 minutes to perform its operation. Until that in the progress dialog, only the progress text is visible. The progress bar doesn't move at all. I set the ProgressText in the WiX file. How can i make the progress bar to move, so that it will be much user friendly. Now its just idle. It makes the feeling that the installer is struck in that action.

Could someone please help me, how to give value to the progress control from C# DTF Custom Action.

Thanks,
Varun

Answer (score 3):

What are you during the immediate execution that takes 5 minutes to execute?   Note: CA's that change system state should run in deferred execution.  The immediate CA should only be generating the CustomActionData property to drive the work to be done during the transaction.

Otherwise you'll use Session.Message and Record class to send progress messages.  Google for MsiProccessMessage for examples in other languages that can be converted over easily.